# Changing styles only when a Vue component is rendered

Tags: vue.js

I'm currently using vue-router to send us to an about page like so:

```
# @/views/About
<template>
  <p>About Vue...</p>
</template>
<script>
[...]
</script>
<style>

</style>
```

The way routes are rendered are like so:

```
# @/App.vue
<template>
  <Header />
  <router-view>
</template>
<script>
  import ...
</script>
<style>
  header {
    background: black;
  }
</style>
```

### Question:

How would I go about changing the header background color ONLY when I am on the About.vue (if i go to other routes like `/` or `/contact` header should stay the same)?

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: add `scoped` keyword to the style tag as follow :`<style scoped>`

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim To the <About /> component <style>? Does not work...

Comment: yes in `about` component style

Comment: it sounds like you need [Vue router API: router.currentRoute](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-currentroute)

Comment: @Sphinx Could you provide a code example for this solution so I can make it the answer if it works? :)

Comment: Hah, uses `this.$route` will be better as @Husam Ibrahim already pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a watcher or a computed property to watch your `this.$route` then conditionally apply a class or style based on if you're currently on the `/about` route. For example ..

```
# @/App.vue
<template>
  <Header :class="[altBackground ? 'header-red' : 'header-black']" />
  <router-view>
</template>
<script>
  import ...
  computed: {
      altBackground() {
          const path = this.$route.path.split('/')
          return path[path.length-1].toLowerCase() === 'about'
      }
  }
</script>
<style>
  .header-black {
    color: black;
  }
  .header-red {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: uses `this.$route.path === '/About'`, i don't think it need to be splited first. or uses `this.$route.name`

Comment: @Sphinx I don't know I thought he might be in a nested route so I thought I should take that into account.

Comment: Works perfectly - Ended up using path.join('/')